# BibLaTeX citations style with four letters

Tags: biblatex

The guideline says, that the citation style must have four letters of the author, a nonbreakable space and the last two digits of the year.  Using BibLaTeX with the option 'style=alphabetic' comes close.  But this style only uses three letters and does lack the space.

Here comes the MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{longfellow:limmericks,
  author    = {Longfellow, Louis},
  title     = {Long Lasting Last Limmericks},
  publisher = {Limmerick Lounge},
  year      = {2022}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{longfellow:limmericks}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is what is looks like.  Instead of the demanded [Long 22] it gives [Lon22].

[image: Output with only 3 letters]

How to change this?

Comment: How do you want multiple author works to appear?

Comment: I would want the numeric style to be used, but I am in no position to make a choice.  As in DG's solution, only the first author should be considered :-(

Comment: The reason I asked is that the label system is sophisticated enough to make labels out of multiple authors, e.g. using the first letter of each author (up to some maximum).

Comment: @AlanMunn Maybe you have guessed from my answer, that I would really appreciate, if the system would respect the other authors as well.  But as said above: I am not in the position to make choices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` to format the label:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{longfellow:limmericks,
  author    = {Longfellow, Louis},
  title     = {Long Lasting Last Limmericks},
  publisher = {Limmerick Lounge},
  year      = {2022}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
   \labelelement{
      \field[strwidth=4,strside=left,names=1,noalphaothers=true]{labelname}
   }
   \labelelement{
      \literal{\nobreakspace}
   }
   \labelelement{
      \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
   }
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{longfellow:limmericks}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I love LaTeX for its versatility and this community for sharing generously its knowledge.  :-)  Thank you very much for this answer. Works perfect!